# Your server is running PHP version 5.4.45 but WordPress 5.2.2 requires at least 5.6.20

Tags: wordpress

how can i overcome that issues.

Comment: It clearly says to update the PHP version, which I am not sure really feasible. Or you can try to update the bootstrap script to use WordPress 5.1

Comment: **Danger**: PHP 5.x (all of it, including 5.6) is beyond end of life and doesn't get security updates. Upgrade to a supported version of PHP.

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj — If it isn't feasible to upgrade PHP then they are in serious trouble.

Answer (score 1):

According to the official WordPress site, WordPress 5.2 requires a minimum of PHP 5.6.20. If you are upgrading to WordPress 5.2 you have to confirm that the server your WordPress running on has at least PHP 5.6.20 (better switch to PHP 7.3X).

Users running PHP versions below 5.6.X (e.g. 5.4.45) have had a notification in their dashboard that includes information to help them update PHP. Since then, the WordPress stats have shown an increase in users on more recent versions of PHP instead of PHP 5.4.45.

So the fix is to upgrade your PHP if you are running a VPS on your own or ask the hosting service provider to upgrade PHP so that you would be able to update WordPress to the latest version.

You can read more here...

https://www.quora.com/How-can-you-fix-your-server-is-running-PHP-version-5-4-45-but-WordPress-5-2-requires-at-least-5-6-20-on-WordPress

Answer (score 0):

You need to install in your server a PHP version above 5.6.20

Follow [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.php) manual

Answer (score 0):

you need to update Wordpress and also update PHP version at least 5.6 or above